# Bitvector operations: M & (N-1)

Tags: collections, bit-manipulation, bitvector

I'm dealing with collections represented as a bitvector.
Last I saw something like M & (N-1). Both M and N are collections, both non empty.

What means the outcome of this in terms of collections?

Comment: No idea, depends on N. What is N? I'd expect that either N=M or N is a single-bit mask, but it could be something more complicated.

Comment: N /= M.  Let's say we're working on a 5 bit machine. I tested it with  M=11011 and N=00111 so M & (N-1) becomes 00010.  I have no clue.

Comment: N pretty much has to be something more interesting than "arbitrary number", or else it doesn't really mean anything.